# Cursor: pointer problems on Mac Chrome

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, mouse-cursor

Recently my website which I've been working on has stopped showing the cursor as a pointer on links, where I intend to use a pointer type of cursor. I've restarted Chrome, checked other websites and they seem to have the same issue. The cursor switches to pointer for a couple milliseconds then it switches back to normal cursor.

Anyone having the same problems?

Comment: Not sure what the explanation for this is, but it's a macOS issue that I've seen many times on my computer and coworkers'. Computer just needs a restart. Would love to know more about it if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to **restart the computer**.

If still doesn't work check if a **Chrome Extension** is causing it.

In Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and go to the Computed styles panel inside the Dev Tools. Select any link and look for the cursor property, then see where it's modified. Here you have [a blog that talks about it](https://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector.html).

[> > > Inspect me < < <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986565/cursor-pointer-problems-on-mac-chrome/#)

Comment: restarting chrome worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is disable hardware acceleration. I had the same problem and it was extremely frustating. Like you I tried restarting the computer and chrome, but nothing worked. Give that a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).